# Why do we have $Pr(U_1>u_1|U_2>u_2)=1/Pr(U_2>u_2) \int^\infty_{u_2}Pr(U_1>u_1|U_2=u_2)\phi(u_2)du_2$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I encountered the following derivation:

$$Pr(U_1>u_1|U_2>u_2)=1/Pr(U_2>u_2) \int^\infty_{u_2}Pr(U_1>u_1|U_2=u_2)\phi(u_2)du_2$$

for bivariate normally distributed  $(U_1,U_2)$. I wonder why this equality holds. Does this have anything to do with the law of total probability? I don't think the law directly applies to this case.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what does $\phi(\cdot)$ mean. Is the integral supposed to be in the numerator or denominator? I believe that what you're looking at is just the definition of conditional probability $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

Comment: $\phi$ is the pdf of a standard normal random variable, and the integral is in the numerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\phi(u_2)$ is the distribution function of $u_2$, we have:

Let $A$ be the event that $U_1>u_1$ and B the event that $U_2>u_2$. Than we have, by your image

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}$$
Now, we have
$$P(A,B)=P(U_2>u_2,U_1>u_1)=\int_{u_2}^\infty\int_{u_1}^\infty p(U_1=u_1,U_2=u_2)du_1du_2$$
Because there seems to be a precomputed $P(U_1>u_1|U_2=u_2)$ this simplyfies to
$$P(A,B)=\int_{u_2}^\infty P(U_1>u_1|U_2=u_2)p(U_2=u_2)du_2$$
which is, given that $p(U_2=u_2)=\phi(u_2)$, equal to
$$P(A,B)=\int_{u_2}^\infty P(U_1>u_1|U_2=u_2)\phi(u_2)du_2$$
And because $P(B)=P(U_2>u_2)$
$$P(U_1>u_1|U_2>u_2)=\frac{\int_{u_2}^\infty P(U_1>u_1|U_2=u_2)\phi(u_2)du_2}{P(U_2>u_2)}$$

Comment: Why do we have $\displaystyle \int_{u_1}^\infty p(U_1=u_1,U_2=u_2)du_1=P(U_1>u_1|U_2=u_2)p(U_2=u_2)$?

Comment: $$\int_{u_1}^\infty p(U_1=u_1|U_2=u_2)p(U_2=u_2)du_1=P(U_1>u_1|U_2=u_2)p(U_1=u_1)$$
because it simply integrates the probability measure over the event $U_1>u_1$. The expression is a tautology.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!